# Will addSpeech() substitute a word within a String of text on Android TTS?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

When I addSpeech("hello","hello.wav") and speak("hello")  using Android TTS, the tts plays the wav file I need. 
However if I call tts.speak("hello there") it speaks in the tts voice itself.

Is there any way to make the Android TTS substitute the saved speech within a string automatically?

Comment: Have you tried breaking your speech up into multiple utterances? So just speak("hello") followed by speak("there").

Comment: Yes, but there's a pause in between which makes it sound staccato. Combining the wav files sounds much more natural.

Comment: Could you render the chunks to wav, then play them all at once to avoid the processing lag? Unfortunately there's no in-line substitution, so that might be as good as it gets.

Comment: That would work too, is there any available library that could create a new .wav file for me given a set of .wav files?